# Invoking AppleScript from Mail Rule

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email, gmail

While working on an AppleScript to save message attachments from a mail rule I believe I have come across what appears to be a limitation. It seems that if you invoke an AppleScript from a mail rule it must always be the last action in the mail rule. For example my script will save the message attachments and when it returns I want the next mail rule action to Archive the message. Mail however reorders the actions and archives the message first then executes the AppleScript. I have resorted to archiving the message within the script but am getting some unusual behavior which I haven't quite figured out. Anybody else encounter this?

Comment: Could it be that the AppleScript is hung or leaves an open input handle? I have an AppleScript app that i run as a login item. The script does it’s task, but the system never shows that the script finishes because it display continuously in the menu bar’s fear icon.